# Configure xunit.console.clr4.exe output path

Tags: xunit

I would like to reconfigure the directory path the xunit.console.clr4.exe logs to?

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using xunit 1.9x than add `/nunit test_results_file_name.xml`.
For example: `xunit.console.clr4.exe path\to\your\tests.dll \nunit path_to\test_results.xml`

If you are using xunit 2.0, prefix with a dash, for example `-nunit`, or `-html`.

A complete example would be: `xunit.console.exe path\to\your\Tests.dll -nunit path_to/test_results.xml -html path_to/test_results.html`

Or you can just push the console output to any file using `>`